# LINQ to SQL Group By Multiple Records in One Row

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Sorry, I don't know how to describe in words, that's why the poor title.

I have a table as follows:

```
UserID Date Description
1 17/11/2020 09:00 Sign in
2 17/11/2020 09:00 Sign in
2 17/11/2020 12:00 Sign out
2 17/11/2020 13:00 Sign in
2 17/11/2020 16:00 Sign out
1 17/11/2020 17:00 Sign out
```

I am creating a report from this data. I need to show data as follows:

```
Date UserID SignIn SignOut
1 17/11/2020 09:00 17:00
2 17/11/2020 09:00 12:00
2 17/11/2020 13:00 16:00
```

I know I need to group on date and user but I need help getting the sign in/out times in the same row.

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation using `row_number()`:

```
select userid,
       max(case when description = 'Sign in' then date end) as signin,
       max(case when description = 'Sign out' then date end) as signout
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by userid, description order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by userid, seqnum
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go. Any chance you know the Linq to SQL for this?